# "Go back to the previous version of Windows 10" unavailable even though I updated *today*

Tags: windows-10

This morning I needed to reboot, and Windows 10 insisted on updating to the May 2020 feature update.

Later I started running into a weird problem and decided undoing that May 2020 update would be a good troubleshooting step.

But I can't:

[image: Go back to the previous version of Windows 10: This option is no longer available because your PC was updated more than 10 days ago.]

I don't understand why Windows 10 is saying I updated more than 10 days ago when in fact it was less than 1 day ago.

Is there a way I can get Windows 10 to change its mind and let me remove the May 2020 feature update?

Comment: Maybe a feature update is not a new "version", look in windows update> update history> and see if you can remove it there.

Comment: It is likely that the computer updated more than 10 days ago and now (for whatever reason) tried updating again. What is going wrong?  That may be easier to fix than trying to install an older version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turned out, apparently the May 2020 feature update isn't a "previous version."

But all was not lost; I discovered there was a System Restore point created when I updated.

I performed the System Restore and, after a few minutes, my system was restored to its state before the May 2020 feature update, as evidenced by the fact that the May 2020 feature update is now being offered to me again.

Unfortunately...it didn't fix the actual issue I'm having.  But that's a separate question.

Comment: (a) If feature updates are previous versions, then we're back to the 10 days thing not making any sense.  (b) I don't care when the May 2020 update was released.  I didn't *install* it 10 days ago, so whether it's a bug in the detection of that date or a bug in the text, it's wrong.  (c) I didn't time the System Restore.  I don't know what you consider a few minutes.  It was long enough to be a boring wait, if that helps.  

Comment: `2004` is a reference to `Windows 10 version 2004` which is known as the `May 2020 Update`.  The reason I assume those things is it would explain the reason, the previous version was removed and you were unable to revert to the previous version without using a Restore Point.